# Change element padding based on element height and parent height with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the size of h1's top padding based on the height of h1 and it's parent.
Padding top would be (h1's height - h1's parent height) / 2

I still don't understand why the JavaScript code isn't working.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  h1.innerHTML = document.title;
  h1.style.paddingTop = (((h1.parentElement.clientHeight - h1.clientHeight) / 2).toString());
  console.log(((h1.parentElement.clientHeight - h1.clientHeight) / 2).toString());
}
```

```css
header {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: First of all, you have to be sure that your element's display as a block to have width and height for it.

Comment: Google automatically sets h1's as display:block. I haven't changed that and it still doesn't work. Though I will look at it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because you have not used a unit to identify the value of evaluated padding. Additionally add `display: block` to the `h1` style. Checkout this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hapajeb/edit?html,js,output) demo.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  h1.innerHTML = document.title;
  h1.style.paddingTop = (((h1.parentElement.clientHeight - h1.clientHeight) / 2).toString())+'vh'; // Use unit.
  console.log(((h1.parentElement.clientHeight - h1.clientHeight) / 2).toString());
}
```

```css
header {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
  position: fixed;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Text</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Still google adds `display:block;` to h1s automatically. Even when I add it myself it does not work.

Comment: Thanks adding a `vh` fixes it.

Comment: If you have checked the jsbin demo, you will find the h1 moved under the header after concatenating the unit to the evaluated padding. This is the main point here regardless any mistake in the equation for the evaluation.